# Top university PhD with preperatory masters OR middle-ranking university straight to PhD

Tags: phd, masters, united-states

I have a problem with my CS PhD application. My research experience is not sufficient for a top university. But I did some solid work and I'm still doing research with the professor after my summer research program ended. I have 3 choices now:

1. Going to some middle-ranking universities (below 25 in USA) with some professors that have some influence in the field.
2. Choosing to go to top universities in their master of research program and pursue a top universities' PhD programs afterwards. I have confidence in myself that I can improve my engineering skill and research ability  significantly while doing a masters.
3. Going to Upenn for their master CIS program. Upenn has a contract with my university and allows around 10 students to go to Upenn for their master under the engineering department. However, Upenn doesn't have a master of research program or a professional master program which makes it risky. Moreover, if I choose to go to Upenn, I should reject all offers. The advantage is that Upenn will release the offer very soon after the deadline and I can focus on my research and intern in high-tech companies.

I'm determined to pursue my PhD in the long run but I also highly value the process. Like what I mentioned in the post. I do not blindly trust the brand of the university. But I see the relevance of other potential resources here.

Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Is location an issue? why do you limit yourself to the US for a PhD? why are you not considering at least Canada?

Comment: Worrying about university rankings when poking around for a PhD is a losing game. You should be looking at potential advisers in your subject of interest and how they've placed their students.

Comment: It seems like #3 is the only concrete (sort of) option.  The remaining options are hypothetical.   I think you are influenced by the brand of a university, and incorrectly equating that to superior education quality or indeed that you will graduate from there.

Comment: @EarlGrey It's actually about my research interest. It seems that only waterloo has a well-organized research group in Canada.

Comment: @AnonymousM It's not actually about poking around for a PhD in my case. I will pursue my PhD anyway. The main problem is how do you feel about doing a preparatory master for PhD if you don't feel urgent about applying a PhD and you don't care about money used in master. The final goal is always PhD :-)

Comment: @VitaminE I know that the professor matters more than the university. And as you mentioned, the first 2 choices are hypothetical.  But the chance of going to top universities for their master program is higher than going to middle-ranking universities for their PhD.  Thus, I must weigh the pros and cons here. Of course, I will only apply to universities that have well-organized research groups no matter master or PhD. But I believe that environments are different among different universities. And it will affect me not just in the narrow case.

Comment: Like the number of conferences held there, students' quality that I get along with, students' attitude toward research, and their talent